# I need to create Nginx Dynamic rewrite rule

Tags: regex, nginx, dynamic, url-rewriting

I need help configuring Dynamic URL rewrite.

```
rewrite  ^/0_050hfe55/index.php?&autoplay=false&automute=true$ https://example.com/index.php?entryId=0_050hfe55
```

I need to rewrite the Entry ID (0_050hfe55) so it will be after index.php index.php?entryId=0_050hfe55

Can anyone help me do this?

Comment: `rewrite` only operates on the part of the URI before the `?`. Are you trying to match only those URIs containing `autoplay=false&automute=true`? You can use `rewrite` to change `/something/index.php?...` to `/index.php?arg=something&...`

Comment: Hello,

I want to match only entry id

https://example.com/0_050hfe55/index.php?&autoplay=false&automute=true
->
https://example.com/index.php?entryId=0_050hfe55&autoplay=false&automute=true


Like this, so 0_050hfe55 will go after index.php (index.php?entryId=0_050hfe55)

And 0_050hfe55  is dynamic.

Comment: What pattern matches `0_050hfe55`?

Comment: Well, i was able to resolve the issue.